# Why does omitting parenthesis when calling a function in JavaScript update slider output correctly, but when including the parenthesis creates bug

Tags: javascript

My slider output which reads the value given/updated by user using oninput event handler does not update correctly when I call using

```
slider.oninput = updateGridRange();
```

syntax with parenthesis, rather it gives me the same default value of 16x16. However the code works great without that bug when I call using

```
slider.oninput = updateGridRange;
```

What is the difference in JavaScript when I call a function with no parameters defined `functionExample()` and `functionExample` without parentheses? Why is there a bug created in my code when this situation happens?

```
function createSlider() {
  const slider = document.createElement('input');
  slider.setAttribute('type', 'range');
  slider.setAttribute('min', '1');
  slider.setAttribute('max', '100');
  slider.setAttribute('value', '16');
  document.querySelector('div.slider-container').appendChild(slider);

  const sliderText = document.createElement('div');
  sliderText.classList.add('slider-text');
  document.querySelector('div.slider-container').insertBefore(sliderText, document.querySelector('div.slider-container').firstChild);
  
  sliderText.textContent = `${slider.value} x ${slider.value}`;
  slider.oninput = updateGridRange; //updateGridRange() causes bug
}

function updateGridRange() {
  document.querySelector('div.slider-container div.slider-text').textContent = `${document.querySelector('input').value} x ${document.querySelector('input').value}`;
}
```

Pictures of Slider

Bug

[image]

Good

[image]

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, ***[search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=funtion+with+or+without+parenthesis+site%3Astackoverflow.com);*** if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score -1):

`updateGridRange` is the function itself, and that's what you need to pass.

`updateGridRange()` is *the result of* calling `updateGridRange`, that is, it is whatever value is returned by calling `updateGridRange`.

Since you don't have a return value for the `updateGridRange` function, `updateGridRange()` is really just the same thing as `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

When doing

```
slider.oninput = updateGridRange;
```

you are assigning the function in the variable named `updateGridRange`, and it will be called *later* (a callback).

You only want it to fire when `slider.oninput` event happens, so you don't want to call the function immediately.  Putting parenthesis on the end of a variable that holds a function will invoke it immediately, which is why you get bad behavior.